# Write only the output from the console command

Tags: c#, .net, console, outputstream

I'm trying to build a .net application that will run some console commands (like running phantomJs) and return me the outcome of the operations. But by default I'm getting everything from the starting of `cmd.exe` to closing it. Any ideas for a quick fix or do I need to play with regexes ?

Here's my code as for now :

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

System.Diagnostics.Process proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
System.IO.StreamReader sOut = proc.StandardOutput;

System.IO.StreamWriter sIn = proc.StandardInput;

sIn.WriteLine("phantomjs -v");
sIn.WriteLine("EXIT");

proc.Close();

string results = sOut.ReadToEnd().Trim();

sIn.Close();
sOut.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the different streams. Why not use `cmd` as `filename` and pass it the `-c "phantomjs -v"` as argument. Then use `proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()` to grab everything that is outputted in the console. This should leave out unneeded info as it only reads what the output of the executed command is.

Following code might not work, but should give you the general idea.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = "cmd";
psi.Arguments = "/c \"phantomjs -v\"";
psi.UseShellExecute = false;
psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
// Optional other options

Process proc = Process.Start(psi);

string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

proc.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: with your solution I'm not getting the output from phastomjs version as well as I still need to write `sIn.WriteLine("EXIT");` to the input stream to close the command line.

Comment: Added `UseShellExecute` and `RedirectStandardOutput`. This should be enough to get the output. Also noticed it should be `/c` instead of `-c` .

Answer (score 2):

PhantomJS is an executable (according to their docs) - why not execute that directly rather than running cmd.exe?  That will avoid the cmd.exe noise.

Or redirect the output of phantomjs to a log file and load the log file.

Or if you absolutely have to use cmd.exe and can't redirect ... I'd maybe throw some echo sentinels around the phantomjs to serve as parse start/stop points.

e.g.,

```
echo PARSE START
runcommand.exe
echo PARSE STOP
```

But don't do that.

Comment: I've tried `new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("phantomjs -v")` as well as with phantomjs.exe but it brings error : `The system cannot find the file specified`. Or it should be executed differently ?

Comment: @mike_hornbeck It's just expecting the filename there, you need to put the arguments in the `Arguments` property.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on an unix machine:

```
sIn.WriteLine("phantomjs -v > /dev/null");
```

Windows:

```
sIn.WriteLine("phantomjs -v > NUL");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that the following would be helpful!

```
{

 Process xyProcess = new Process();

 xyProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "FilenameYouWant";
 xyProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 xyProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 xyProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
 xyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
 xyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 xyProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

 xyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments += "any arg1 you want ";
 xyProcess.StartInfo.Arguments += "any arg2 you want ";

 xyProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
 xyProcess.OutputDataReceived += process_DataReceived;

 // Start the process
 xyProcess.Start();
 xyProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
 xyProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
 xyProcess.WaitForExit();

}
static private void process_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    //Catch the process response here
}
```